# Issue in ipython matplotlib in the manual zoom function

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, anaconda

Running the following in the ipython console

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib
test_numbers = np.ones((1000,1), dtype=float)
test_numbers[500] = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(test_numbers)
```

will give the proper plot as expected. Using the manual zoom on the figure window that had been subsequentially created will zoom in as desired. However, if using the 'back' or 'home' button in the created figure window will set the axis scaling to ([0,1], [0,1]).
Worse, if I change the size of my figure on the data that I actually am looking at and use the zoom and back functions will created the following error

```
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 155, in __draw_idle_agg
self.draw()
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 127, in draw
super(FigureCanvasQTAggBase, self).draw()
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 430, in draw
self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1299, in draw
renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
a.draw(renderer)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2437, in draw
mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 138, in _draw_list_compositing_images
a.draw(renderer)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1133, in draw
ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 974, in _update_ticks
tick_tups = list(self.iter_ticks())
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 917, in iter_ticks
majorLocs = self.major.locator()
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1061, in __call__
self.refresh()
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1081, in refresh
dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 839, in viewlim_to_dt
return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 445, in num2date
return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
File "C:\Users\mypath\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 260, in _from_ordinalf
dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Please comment to let me know how to provide the proper version information that is required (`print(matplotlib.__version)` does not work). I will update the question accordingly.

Python version 3.6.3

IPython 6.2.1

conda 4.4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is a memory problem**

I tried to reproduce the error today and realized that the example works fine if there is not a huge pandas dataframe (size (450016, 35)) uploaded.